# Symmetric group action on polynomials

Tags: polynomials, group-theory

I am working with polynomials in several variables with the obvious action of $S_n$. That is, given a polynomial $f$ in the variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$, a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ acts on $f$ by sending $x_i$ to $x_{\sigma(i)}$.

What I would like to do is to give Mathematica a polynomial, for example

$x_1^2x_2 + x_3$

and have it compute the image of this under the action of a particular element. For example, if I gave it $(123)$ it would output

$x_2^2x_3 + x_1$.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is basic and intrinsic functionality...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a start.

```
groupElementAction[expr_, vars_, perm_] /;

  Length[perm] == Length[vars] && PermutationListQ[perm] :=

 expr /. Thread[vars -> Permute[vars, perm]]
```

That example:

```
groupElementAction[x1^2*x2 + x3, {x1, x2, x3}, {2, 3, 1}]

(* Out[131]= x2 + x1 x3^2 *)
```

With some tweaking it can be made to handle the explicit cycle form of permutation group elements.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has been very helpful. I changed the last line to be "...Permute[vars,Cycles[{perm}]]" and that seems to accept cycle notation